# How can I claim my BCH if my BTC is held with Block.io, a multisig address?

Tags: blockchain-fork, multi-signature, bitcoin-cash, cross-chain-recovery, block.io

Title is enough, but to elaborate, I've been trying to do this for a long time with no avail, I am trying to cash out my BCH, but first I need to acquire it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution. I've got my BCH today from block.io which was already empty but it had a BTC on the day of fork. 
So what you have to do is:

First of all you should get from security settings of you block.io profile: "Redeem Script Hex", and two private keys. (actually you will have some more strings and values but only these three required to claim your BCH.

After that:

Go to http://www.motelmaya.com/BCH/BCH.html

I know this seems strange and may cause doubts and believe me I wasn't sure too. But the real deal was: getting BCH (I had 0,5 of BTC at block.io wallet) or getting nothing.

So, then:

- Click +TX or New -> Transaction.
  Enter the redeem HEX that you received from block.io in the first box (Address, WIF key or Redeem Script)
- Click on "Advanced options" -> "Network" -> Settings and change the network to "Bitcoin Cash (mainnet)"
- Click New -> Transaction once more.
- Put in the amount you want to transfer and the address you are sending to (your new BCH wallet I guess - I've used my blockchain.info wallet address), make sure that the fee is not too high (I've entered something like 0.000317
- Click "Submit", you will get a long HEX string. copy it
- Click "Sign", paste the copied string, paste the first private key from the  block.io to the "Private key" field, click "Submit", copy the string.
- Paste the string into the second box (below the "Private key" field), paste the second private key from the block.io, click Submit, copy the output
- Go to "Broadcast", paste the string and click "Submit".

That's it. You will recieve TXid which you will be able to check at https://bitcoincash.blockexplorer.com

Actually all regards should go to [ohad serfaty](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/64264/ohad-serfaty) but I can't comment the post where he advised this method because of low reputation.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You already have the answer in your title.

BTC held on **multisig** address are **not yours**. They belong to you and your parnter. To get BCH from this address you either need the signature from him.

Comment: I believe that i am the sole owner, as i can access my private keys, I may have worded something incorrectly. I am able to retrieve the unspent inputs from my address in a coinb.in transaction, but when i put in the 36 character coinomi address and click submit, it says One or more input or output is invalid.

I had spaces in the address like a newb, i am now looking at this

The transaction below has been generated and encoded. It can be broadcasted once it has been signed.